# React Router, two level routing doesnt work for me

Tags: reactjs, react-router

not sure if this is enough info, but I have a hunch this is where the problem lies,  how I am writing the "to"

```
    let categories = body.categories.map((category) => {
      return ( <div className="eachCategory" key = {category._id} onClick = {(e) => this.updateHistoryAndSearch({tree: body.tree,category: category._id})}>

         <Link to={`/Browse/${category._id}`}> {category._id}  </Link>

         </div>                       
      )

    })
```

on a separate page my route looks like

```
<Route path={"/Browse/:category"}  component={this.Lectures} />
```

Comment: are you getting any error in the console? share your webpack.config.js file

Comment: what is this.Lectures

Comment: I am using create-react-app so didnt write the webpack.
this.Lectures is a Component with an array of lectures that is mapped through similar to how categories is.

Comment: Which version of create-react-app ?
There could be a conflict between react-router 2 (veeeeery old) and create-react-app latest version which relies on React 16.

Comment: @ChrisR I don't think the OP is referring to the v2 of React. What he means is `two level routes`

Comment: "react": "^16.0.0"
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: correct,  I mean my <Link to="/Browse" is working fine,  I can't figure out why when I try to add something after "/Browse" it wont work   like /:category"